# python removing specific non-ASCII characters from a string

Tags: python, string

I have searched for a solution online but this question is different, since I don't want to remove all non-ASCII chars, just a specific part of them.

I have a line that looks like that:

```
"[x+]4 gur Id lú gal sik-kát ⌈ x x ⌉ [……………]"
```

I want to remove **only** these chars:

```
'…' , '⌉' , '⌈'
```

The text is from [here](http://www.achemenet.com//fr/item/?/sources-textuelles/textes-par-langues-et-ecritures/babylonien/archives-ebabbar/1652393).

I tried to solve it using `replace` but whenever I write one of these non-ASCII chars I'm getting the following error line:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file C:/-------.py on line --, but no encoding declared;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that `ú` is non-ascii too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'[x+]4 gur Id lú gal sik-kát ⌈ x x ⌉ [……………]'.encode().decode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```

out:

```
'[x+]4 gur Id l gal sik-kt  x x  []'
```

use encode to convert string to bytes, and decode it by `ascii` and igore the error.

I think you should use `re.sub` :

```
import re

text = "[x+]4 gur Id lú gal sik-kát ⌈ x x ⌉ [……………]"

re.sub('[…⌉⌈]', '', text)  # this will replace all the element in [] with ''
```

out:

```
'[x+]4 gur Id lú gal sik-kát  x x  []'
```

Comment: but i want to keep the ú and á

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate),

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import string

s = "[x+]4 gur Id lú gal sik-kát ⌈ x x ⌉ [……………]"
r = s.translate(None, '…⌉⌈')

print(r)
# [x+]4 gur Id lú gal sik-kát  x x  []
```

Comment: it's not working - SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file C:/----------.py on line 57, but no encoding declared;

Comment: @Yonlif, add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the file. Checked the updated answer.